# Photoshop plugin to compare the design (mock) versus generated HTML

Tags: html, plug-in, photoshop, sketch

Is there a direct tool/plugin for comparing the design file which can be in skecth, PSD format with the generated HTML?

The comparison can be the below mentioned points :

- alignment between the modules
- font check etc

Please not that currently we are already using tools like **page ruler** etc to manually check the spacing between elements. But it requires lot of time and some alignment issues are still skipped.

It would be great to know about a tool, which auto compares all the spacing , alignment and font styles and display the results at once.